# Buffer Mode MPI does not work as I understand

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi, hpc, mpi4py

I have multiple producer and one consumer processes. Each process is launched by `MPIPoolExecutor` class. First I launch the consumer process and then starts launching producer processes using `starmap` method. Consumer accepts receives data and save it to hard drive. Each producer process will create a buffer with the same size as the data needs to be sent and send it using the blocker method `bsend`. I am expecting each producer process to dump the data into the buffer and exit. However, I am noticing a delay where it looks like each producer process waits for the data to be consumed by the consumer process. What am I missing? My code goes like this:

```
def consumer(args...):
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    file = tb.open_file(file_name, 'w')
    filters = tb.Filters(complevel=5, complib='blosc')
    array = file.create_carray(file.root, 'data', tb.Float32Atom(), shape=(n_, n_), filters=filters)
    for i in range(num_tasks):
        t = time.time()
        idxs, data = MPI.Comm.recv()
        print("time for waiting --consumer ", time.time() - t)
        array[idxs,:] = data

def producer(args...):
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    #adding 1000 just to be in the safe side.
    mem = MPI.Alloc_mem(data.nbytes + idxs.nbytes + 1000)
    MPI.Attach_buffer(mem)
    #Since consumer is launched first, it guarantees to get a rank of 1. 
    MPI.Comm.bsend([idxs, data], 1)
    MPI.Detach_buffer()


....
with MPIPoolExecutor() as executor:
  executor.starmap(consumer, [(args)])
  executor.starmap(produces, list_of_args)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the consumer is launched first, it gets rank zero, not 1. Also: you're misunderstanding buffered communication. If you want the producer to return, use `MPI_Isend`. The buffer detach call blocks until all messages in it have been completed.